# How to share folder among multiple machines in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

Subj: is it possible? When I mount folder on two guests, host sees files, created on both of them, but they don't see files of other guest.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do it - is share common folder created on the host.

More info on sharing folders: 
http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/VirtualBox_Shared_Folders